# Django ORM - SQL with nested query referencing outer query field

Tags: mysql, django, orm

I’m trying to do a data migration with Django but can’t convert my SQL to efficient Django ORM code. My db tables look like the following:

```
finacial_quarter (id, start_date, end_date)
report (id, add_date, financial_quarter_id)
```

For each record in report, I want to set report.financial_quarter_id to the id of the appropriate record from finacial_quarter, that is, the one where report.add_date falls between financial_quarter.start_date and financial_quarter.end_date.

The SQL for this is trivial:

```
UPDATE report as r SET r.financial_quarter_id = 
   (SELECT id 
    FROM financial_quarter as f 
    WHERE r.add_date >= f.start_date AND r.add_date <= f.end_date)
```

But mapping this to Django’s ORM so that it runs efficiently doesn’t seem possible because there does't appear to be a way to reference out query fields in the inner query.

I can do this easily by looping through all records in report then running another query to get the financial quarter id, but it’s takes ~30 seconds to run the migration (which I will live with in the worst case). Is there a way to write Django code to produce the SQL provided?

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for raw SQL queries? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/sql/

Comment: I would like to avoid raw queries for the day I switch to using another DB

Comment: cross that bridge when you come to it.